# Can second argument in addEventListener be matched with a string?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

AFAIK, second argument in addEventListener is the exact function name which is called after the event happens. I want the second argument in addEventListener to be matched with a string and then that function should be called. Like:

```
var k =0;

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var val=arr[i];
    var link=document.createElement('a');

    link.id='name'+k++;
    link.innerHTML="Name :   " +val.name+"<br/><br/>";

    link.setAttribute('href','#');

    link.addEventListener('click',link.id);   //I want link.id should be the string which is either name0 or name1 or name2 ....
}

function name0(){

}

function name1(){

}

function name2(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I got is you want to add click events and their own handlers to different element dynamically. You can do this using his method:

```
var k =0;

var obj = {
    name0: function (){

    },
    name1: function(){

    },
    name2: function(){

    }
}

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var val=arr[i];
    var link=document.createElement('a');

    link.id='name'+k++;
    link.innerHTML="Name :   " +val.name+"<br/><br/>";

    link.setAttribute('href','#');

    //link.id could be name0, name1 ... and func could be obj[name0], obj[name1], obj[name2].....
    link.addEventListener('click',obj[link.id]);   //I want <br/> link.id should be the string which is either name0 or name1 or name2 ....
}
```

Comment: has any of the answer, resolved your problem. If yes then please accept it, It may help other user. If not then please add comment.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this, would be to wrap your event listeners in an object as follows:

```
var arr = [{name: "zero"}, {name: "one"}];
var listeners = {
    name0: function() {
        alert("Name 0")
    },
    name1: function() {
        alert("Name 1")
    }
}
var k = 0;

for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var val = arr[i];
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.id = 'name' + k++;
    link.innerHTML="Name: " + val.name + "<br/><br/>";
    link.setAttribute('href','#');
    link.addEventListener('click', listeners[link.id]);

    document.body.appendChild(link);
}
```

Fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MLPHL/).